# Symfony - migration update set to null if empty

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I want to update every field in a specific table when running a migration that if it is `''` to be updated with **NULL**.

I have set one of the fields in db to `''` so I can test it.

I am getting an error when running that specific migration:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'DoctrineMigrations\Version20211129141541' for key 'PRIMARY'

And my migration file:

```
    final class Version20211129141541 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        $this->addSql('UPDATE post SET context=NULL WHERE context=""');
        $this->addSql('UPDATE post SET info=NULL WHERE info=""');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {

    }
}
```

Is this anyway the right approach?

Comment: Maybe context or info is a part of primary key. Please add your post entity.

Comment: I think it is saying that you ran that migration already. You can either revert it or delete the entry from the migrations table manually

Comment: It was run already. Thanks for the input. I fix that, but when migration is executed it still does not update the fields. Is there a syntax problem? @ChrisHaas

Comment: If you manually run those, does it do what you expect?